# passing parameters from submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following table with edit button in each. How can I detect which Edit button was clicked?

```
<table width="50%" border="1" height="50%" style='position:relative'><font color = "black">
    <tr>

    <th>SkillSet ID</th>
    <th>SkillSet Name</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>

    <% for skt in @skillset %>
    <tr>

        <td><%= skt.SkillSetID%></td>
        <td><%= skt.SkillSetName%></td>

        <td><%= submit_tag "Edit"-%></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </font></table>
    <br>

    </td>
    </div>
    <%end%>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `name` option of the `submit_tag` method:

```
<%= submit_tag "Edit", :name => "edit[#{skt.id}]" %>
```

Then in your controller you can check the key inside `params["edit"]`, where you should find something like `(skt.id) => ''`

Alternatively, you could add a `hidden_field` to track the id of the `skt` you're editing.

Comment: and how will i access this name it from the controller?

Answer (score 5):

You can use button_tag with type 'submit'.

```
<%= button_tag 'Edit', value: skt.id, type: :submit, name: :edit %>
```

This will produce button with label 'Edit' and it's value skt.id